# how to restrict some options in a select box using Laratrust 5.2.*

Tags: laravel

is there a way of hiding some options in a dropdown select box for a users who are not admins?

My Controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = User::with('roles')->findOrFail($id);
        $roles = Role::all();
        return view('profiles.edit', compact('roles', 'user'));  
    }
```

edit.blade.php

```
 @if(Auth::user()->hasRole(['superadministrator', 'administrator']))
                    <div class="row my-2">
                            <div class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold pt-2">Role:</div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select id="role" name="role" class="form-control @error('role') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('role') }}">
                                        <option value="">Choose user role...</option>
                                            @foreach($roles as $role)
                                                <option value="$role->display_name" {{ $user->hasRole($role->name) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $role->display_name }}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                    @error('role')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endif
```

what I was is, if a user is an administrator, he can only see certain options in the dropdown list and if he is a super administrator, all options are available... is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have an array of items that can be displayed only by admins. You can use that list to hide the items.

```
@foreach($roles as $role)
   @if(!in_array($role->display_name, $adminOptionsLists) ||
       (in_array($role->display_name, $adminOptionsLists) &&
        Auth::user()->isAdmin()) // make your own admin check condition.
   )
    <option 
       value="$role->display_name" {{ $user->hasRole($role->name) ? 'selected' : '' }}
    >
      {{ $role->display_name }}
    </option>
   @endif
@endforeach
```